# jscodeshift - get count of all imports from a module in project

Tags: javascript, jscodeshift

I'm playing around with jscodeshift.

My goal is to get count of all imports from a particular module in a project

`import { Circle, Triangle, Rectangle } from 'geometry';`

results in

`{ Circle: 1, Triangle: 1, Rectangle: 1 }`

I have kind of achieved what I wanted [here](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/853ac1968a0c3f6279fe0a65975a2c7d/ed05979a80e0db934a1f651c10d2dad740dfcbfb)
But the only issue is that I want these stats for a whole project instead of single file.

Any idea how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that you are using the wrong tool for the job. jscodeshift, as the name suggests, is a tool that **modifies** your codebase by analyzing and transforming ASTs, and it works on the file level. In other words, it is meant for modifying file one by one, not for statically analyzing a codebase.

What you showed in the link is really using the parser and the AST tree walker (node visitor) that jscodeshift depends on to aggregate the statistics. For your goal, you need to write a nodeJS script that uses the `glob` tool to find all the js files, a parser that analyzes each of the file (e.g. `acorn` or `@babel/parser` used as default in jscodeshift), and a matching walker (`acorn-walk` or `@babel/traverse`) to find the node and add it to your statistics. Here is an example using `glob`, `@babel/parser` and `@babel/traverse` (just as an example, I haven't run the code)

```
import * as glob from 'glob';
import * as fs from 'node:fs';
import * as parser from '@babel/parser';
import traverse from '@babel/traverse';

glob('**/*.js', {}, (err, files) => {
    if (err) {
        // handle error
    }

    files.forEach(file => {
        const code = fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf-8');
        const ast = parser.parse(code, {
            sourceType: 'module'
        });
        traverse(ast, {
            ImportDeclaration (path) {
                // handle your statistics
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if I understand this correctly, are you trying to import everything from within a module without having to explicitly type their names (Circle, Triangle, etc)?
Or this might help:

```
export const Foo = 1;
export const Bar = 2;

// geometry2.js|ts
export const Biz = 3;

// index.js|ts 
import * as counts from './geometry';
import * as counts2 from './geometry2';

const data = { ...counts, ...counts2 };
console.log(data); // logs {Foo: 1, Bar: 2, Biz: 3}
```

Comment: No, I actually want to check that how many times a function/component has been imported from a particular module within a whole project